# Selenium Junits on headless browser

Tags: selenium

I have recorded scripts through Selenium IDE and converted them to JUnit 4 Webdriver scripts.
Of course converted scripts had to be changed to run smoothly as Junits. Now my next goal is to make these scripts run on CI, So obviously I need some headless browser for this purpose. I found some threads, but I am looking for Junits specifically.

What could be the best solution/approach for this, any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a headless browser for CI runs. Why not just stick to a standard basic installation of Firefox or Chrome? Why the 'need' to use a headless browser?

Comment: Well,my CI is running on EC2 instance, So assume I need to install headless browser ..if not, am I missing something in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is a headless WebKit-based browser and there is Selenium WebDriver for that called [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).

That's what i use and is OK but there is also the option of using a headed browser like Firefox or Chrome and then use Xvfb to ignore screen output.

Comment: I am able to do this task using selenium chrome driver on my windows machine and everything works fine, but I want to package this program as a jar and run on linux machine as part of a browserless automation. 

I tried Chrome Headless driver. All the steps are getting executed successfully and in the log statement i see success with the id for all the component which got created but when I login to the application these elements are not even created Is that I am missing any configuration?

Comment: The configuration I am using:
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<chromedrier_path>");ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");